# Compute Launch Button Tooltip error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Using `Eclipse` I get this error:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Answer (score 0):

Add "**-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU**"

to eclipse.ini file and this solved my problem.

Also Clean your Projects from your IDE.

For more info [Visit Link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=270446)

Comment: The referenced bug was fixed more than 8 years ago in Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: Yes, maybe the questioner is using an outdated Eclipse version. Or the error is caused by an installed plugin.

Comment: So he should update the eclipse may be Neon or Oxygen

Comment: He or she should make sure to use the latest version of Eclipse which is currently Eclipse Photon (4.8): http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/